# Visual C++/CLR WinForms - PictureBox not working

Tags: visual-c++, picturebox

I made a simple form with a PictureBox control in Visual C++ CLR WinForms (Visual Studio 2022).

I added an image to PictureBox and tried to run the program, but I got an error:

[image]

Where is the problem?